# Tooltip not showing on DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn

Tags: c#, winforms

I am dynamically adding a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` to my `DataGridView`.

However, I can't seem to add the tooltip to the checkboxes:

```
// Method to Populate the DataGrid
    private void PopulateDataGrid(objPatient patient)
    {
        this.uiDocumentDataGrid.DataSource = DataManager.GetDocumentData(patient);
        // Hide unnecessary columns
        this.uiDocumentDataGrid.Columns["Forename"].Visible = false;
        this.uiDocumentDataGrid.Columns["Surname"].Visible = false;

        // Add column for selection
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn selectedColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        selectedColumn.Name = "Selected";
        selectedColumn.HeaderText = "Attach";
        selectedColumn.ReadOnly = false;
        this.uiDocumentDataGrid.Columns.Insert(0,selectedColumn);

        // Set columns except checkbox to readonly
        foreach(DataGridViewColumn c in this.uiDocumentDataGrid.Columns)
        {
            if (c.Index > 0)
            {
                c.ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }

        // Refresh the view in case of draw issues
        this.uiDocumentDataGrid.Refresh();

        // Add tooltip to each checkbox
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in uiDocumentDataGrid.Rows)
        {
            r.Cells["Selected"].ToolTipText = "Check this box to select this document.";
        }

        // Disable the functionality button if no rows.
        if (this.uiDocumentDataGrid.RowCount == 0)
        {
            this.uiSendButton.Enabled = false;
        }

    }
```

No tooltip shows with this method.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The Tooltip appears when the mouse is over the Column Header.

Comment: @LarsTech - Yes it does, with my first code sample.  Should the second code block do it correctly?  What's the code required to do it for each checkbox?

Comment: This MSDN article suggests the `CellFormatting` event: [How to: Add ToolTips to Individual Cells in a Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2249cf0a.aspx)

Comment: I tried your second snippet with the `foreach(...)` and it worked for me.  Obviously, that only works after the rows are added.

Comment: The only way I can duplicate it so far is if I set the ToolTip in the constructor — then it doesn't work.  If I add the ToolTip in the Load event of the form, everything is fine.

Comment: @LarsTech : The datagridview *is* populated in its parent form's constructor.  Is that what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try setting the ToolTip value of cells in the constructor of the form.  Try setting them in the Load or Shown events instead:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
  foreach (DataGridViewRow r in uiDocumentDataGrid.Rows)
  {
    r.Cells["Selected"].ToolTipText = "Check this box to select this document.";
  } 
  base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I wonder why they can't be set in a form's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn selectedColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
   selectedColumn.Name = "Selected";
   selectedColumn.HeaderText = "Attach";
   selectedColumn.ReadOnly = false;
   this.uiDocumentDataGrid.Columns.Insert(0,selectedColumn);
   uiDocumentDataGrid.CellToolTipTextNeeded += new DataGridViewCellToolTipTextNeededEventHandler(uiDocumentDataGrid_CellToolTipTextNeeded);
```

and in the the event handler

```
    void uiDocumentDataGrid_CellToolTipTextNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellToolTipTextNeededEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
            e.ToolTipText = "Check this box to select this document.";
    }
```

Comment: Glad you got it working with the solution from Lars Tech; FYI: I have placed the code inside Form_Load and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this code to the `CellFormatting` event sorted it for me.  I'm adding this answer for posterity but will accept LarsTech's answer as his works too and it was he who point me to this event anway.

```
private void uiDocumentDataGrid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell = this.uiDocumentDataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            cell.ToolTipText = "Check this box to select this document.";
        }
    }
```